# Logging errors and events, best practice?

Tags: vb.net, logging, 3-tier

I'm currently developing a 3-tier application and now I have come to logging, I am curios as to the best practices. Below is my interface and model for a LogEntry, I then implement that in a service called JsonLogService which serializes the entries and stores them in the file system.

```
Public Interface ILogService

    Sub Log(logEntry As LogEntry)
    Sub Log(source As String, type As LogEntryType, message As String)
    Sub Log(source As String, type As LogEntryType, format As String, ParamArray arguments() As Object)

End Interface

Public Enum LogEntryType
    Information
    Warning
    [Error]
    Debug
End Enum

Public Class LogEntry

    Public Property Source As String
    Public Property Type As LogEntryType
    Public Property Message As String
    Public Property LoggedAt As Date = DateTime.Now

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Sub Now(source As String, type As LogEntryType, message As String)
        Me.Source = source
        Me.Type =
        Me.Message = message
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(source As String, type As LogEntryType, format As String, ParamArray arguments() As Object)
        Me.Source = source
        Me.Type = type
        Me.Message = String.Format(format, arguments)
    End Sub
```

I'm currently using this service in my managers to log when events happen which works well, but now I am unsure how to implement this for catching errors.

Does it actually make sense to catch errors in my managers methods because surely my tests should prevent any errors from happening there?

Comment: use Try Catch and log when you get the error

Comment: @Mederic That's ok at a manger level, but what about at the presentation tier? My presentation tier (in my mind) shouldn't access services directly, or should this tier not bother because errors primarily occur at the manager (business logic) tier?

Comment: I don't know really how your app is structured but if you cant access the service directly with the presentation tier. On an error how about doing a data burst sending just error information to the service which will pass it to log interface?

Comment: @Mederic The structure is pretty typically 3-tier. Web, Managers, Services.